Filter expression for C# Dataverse call for associated entity
I have a working Postman GET call with below filter expression
URL calls qacode D365 entity.
"$filter": "qacode_incident/any(o:o/incidentid eq '8e43ab01-1922-4989-8e5d-8d56f9f7f9c1')"

How can we write this filter query while implementing a Dataverse call in C#? I am unable to figure it out.
I don't know what the purpose of '/any(o:o/' in the filter expression is.

is the relationship N:N? in this case a LinkEntity is enough
